# Google Analytics API error in CMD

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm implementing google analytics Api.

When I'm trying to run that it's throwing following error

[image: stack trace]

Comment: You're probably going to want to generate a new key now that you've shared yours with the world.

Comment: @AndréDion:  If there's any consolation, since it's in an image it's not index by web searches.  But yes, this advice is sensible.

Comment: Don't change the context of your question after you ask it... Either mark this one resolved, delete it and/or open an entirely new question. If I were you I'd take my time reading the documentation as it seems you're missing key steps that are clearly outlined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're following the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py), and it looks like you've set `key_file_location` to the raw key value instead of to the **client_secrets.p12** key file you're supposed to download and include in the project:

Line 98:

```
key_file_location = '<Replace with /path/to/generated/client_secrets.p12>'
```